# react native bundle exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at BundleDeltaClient

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run react-native RNTester demo app, but after the bundlingthe app crashes with below exception.

```
12-12 21:05:08.640 25808-25834/com.facebook.react.uiapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.facebook.react.uiapp, PID: 25808
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY
        at android.util.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:408)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDeltaClient$BundleDeltaJavaClient.processDelta(BundleDeltaClient.java:103)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDeltaClient.processDelta(BundleDeltaClient.java:71)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDownloader.processBundleResult(BundleDownloader.java:314)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDownloader.access$200(BundleDownloader.java:37)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDownloader$1.onResponse(BundleDownloader.java:174)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

> Package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-native",
  "version": "1000.0.0",
  "description": "A framework for building native apps using React",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:facebook/react-native.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.3"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "requirePragma": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "bracketSpacing": false,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "parser": "flow"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|mp4|png|psd|svg|webp)$": "<rootDir>/jest/assetFileTransformer.js",
      ".*": "./jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest/setup.js"
    ],
    "timers": "fake",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^React$": "<rootDir>/Libraries/react-native/React.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "/__tests__/.*-test\\.js$",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/template",
      "Libraries/Renderer",
      "RNTester/e2e"
    ],
    "haste": {
      "defaultPlatform": "ios",
      "hasteImplModulePath": "<rootDir>/jest/hasteImpl.js",
      "providesModuleNodeModules": [
        "react-native"
      ],
      "platforms": [
        "ios",
        "android"
      ]
    },
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!react|fbjs|react-native|react-transform-hmr|core-js|promise)/",
      "node_modules/react/node_modules/fbjs/",
      "node_modules/react/lib/ReactDOM.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/Map.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/Promise.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/fetch.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/ErrorUtils.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/URI.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/Deferred.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/PromiseMap.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/areEqual.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/base62.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/crc32.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/everyObject.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/fetchWithRetries.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/filterObject.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/flattenArray.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/forEachObject.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/isEmpty.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/removeFromArray.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/resolveImmediate.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/someObject.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/sprintf.js",
      "node_modules/fbjs/lib/xhrSimpleDataSerializer.js",
      "node_modules/jest-cli",
      "node_modules/react/dist",
      "node_modules/fbjs/.*/__mocks__/",
      "node_modules/fbjs/node_modules/"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "node_modules/react/",
      "Libraries/Renderer",
      "promise",
      "source-map",
      "fastpath",
      "denodeify",
      "fbjs"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "Libraries/**/*.js"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/__tests__/",
      "/vendor/",
      "<rootDir>/Libraries/react-native/"
    ]
  },
  "main": "Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js",
  "files": [
    ".flowconfig",
    "android",
    "cli.js",
    "flow",
    "flow-github",
    "init.sh",
    "scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh",
    "scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh",
    "scripts/launchPackager.bat",
    "scripts/launchPackager.command",
    "scripts/packager.sh",
    "scripts/react-native-xcode.sh",
    "jest-preset.json",
    "jest",
    "lib",
    "rn-get-polyfills.js",
    "Libraries",
    "LICENSE",
    "packager",
    "react.gradle",
    "React.podspec",
    "React",
    "ReactAndroid",
    "ReactCommon",
    "README.md",
    "third-party-podspecs"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-ci": "JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT=\"reports/junit/js-test-results.xml\" jest --maxWorkers=2 --ci --testResultsProcessor=\"jest-junit\"",
    "flow": "flow",
    "flow-check-ios": "flow check",
    "flow-check-android": "flow check --flowconfig-name .flowconfig.android",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "prettier": "prettier \"./**/*.js\" --write",
    "docker-setup-android": "docker pull reactnativeci/android-base:latest",
    "docker-build-android-base": "docker build -t reactnativeci/android-base -f ContainerShip/Dockerfile.android-base .",
    "docker-build-android": "docker build -t reactnativeci/android -f ContainerShip/Dockerfile.android .",
    "test-android-run-instrumentation": "docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -it reactnativeci/android bash ContainerShip/scripts/run-android-docker-instrumentation-tests.sh",
    "test-android-run-unit": "docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -it reactnativeci/android bash ContainerShip/scripts/run-android-docker-unit-tests.sh",
    "test-android-run-e2e": "docker run --privileged -it reactnativeci/android bash ContainerShip/scripts/run-ci-e2e-tests.sh --android --js",
    "test-android-all": "yarn run docker-build-android && yarn run test-android-run-unit && yarn run test-android-run-instrumentation && yarn run test-android-run-e2e",
    "test-android-instrumentation": "yarn run docker-build-android && yarn run test-android-run-instrumentation",
    "test-android-unit": "yarn run docker-build-android && yarn run test-android-run-unit",
    "test-android-e2e": "yarn run docker-build-android && yarn run test-android-run-e2e",
    "build-ios-e2e": "detox build -c ios.sim.release",
    "test-ios-e2e": "detox test -c ios.sim.release --cleanup"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "absolute-path": "^0.0.0",
    "art": "^0.10.0",
    "base64-js": "^1.1.2",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "commander": "^2.9.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "connect": "^3.6.5",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "denodeify": "^1.2.1",
    "envinfo": "^5.7.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.0",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
    "event-target-shim": "^1.0.5",
    "fbjs": "^1.0.0",
    "fbjs-scripts": "^1.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^1.0.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^3.0.6",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "jest": "24.0.0-alpha.6",
    "jest-junit": "5.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "metro": "0.50.0",
    "metro-babel-register": "0.50.0",
    "metro-core": "0.50.0",
    "metro-memory-fs": "0.50.0",
    "mime": "^1.3.4",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.2.1",
    "npmlog": "^2.0.4",
    "nullthrows": "^1.1.0",
    "opn": "^3.0.2",
    "optimist": "^0.6.1",
    "plist": "^3.0.0",
    "pretty-format": "24.0.0-alpha.6",
    "promise": "^7.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react-clone-referenced-element": "^1.0.1",
    "react-devtools-core": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-local-cli": "1.0.0-alpha.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "semver": "^5.0.3",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.1",
    "shell-quote": "1.6.1",
    "stacktrace-parser": "^0.1.3",
    "ws": "^1.1.5",
    "xcode": "^1.0.0",
    "xmldoc": "^0.4.0",
    "yargs": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/generator": "^7.0.0",
    "@reactions/component": "^2.0.2",
    "async": "^2.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "detox": "9.0.4",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint": "5.1.0",
    "eslint-config-fb-strict": "22.1.0",
    "eslint-config-fbjs": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.43.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "21.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.8.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.5.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.87.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0-alpha.6",
    "jest-junit": "5.2.0",
    "prettier": "1.13.6",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native-dummy": "0.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.8"
  },
  "detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "runner-config": "RNTester/e2e/config.json",
    "specs": "RNTester/e2e",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.release": {
        "binaryPath": "RNTester/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RNTester.app/",
        "build": "xcodebuild -project RNTester/RNTester.xcodeproj -scheme RNTester -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath RNTester/build -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -quiet",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 8"
      },
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "RNTester/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNTester.app/",
        "build": "xcodebuild -project RNTester/RNTester.xcodeproj -scheme RNTester -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath RNTester/build -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -quiet",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 8"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Cloned https://github.com/facebook/react-native project directly.
2. RNTester (gradlew RNTester:android:app:installDebug).
3. Started the npm server (npm start). Bundling completed 100%.
4. As soon as it finish bundling app is crashing.

**Device details:**

- Device tested on : Amazon Fire TV stick, Lenovo Yoga tab 10, Redmi
  4A.
- OS: Windows 10.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you please share your package.json?

Comment: Hi @GodwinVinnyCarole, Updated with the package.json

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the metro bundler was of my some other app already running and I was trying to build another app.

> I solved it by closing the metro bundler and re-build the app

Answer (score 0):

Open the android app with no packager running so you get the red box error about no bundle.
Open the developer menu and select "dev settings" at the bottom.
Untick "DEV MODE"
Start the packager and reload the app
This should really be fixed as instead of being able to jump in and make changes to the core I spent my time trying to just get the example app to run.